# Friendly URLs htaccess and php

Tags: php, url-rewriting

hello **stackoverflow** community hopefully you understand what im trying to do

im working with pretty **URLs**  with `htaccess` and **php** and i have seen in some pages that in the URL appear the title of the news something like...

`http://www.samplePage.com/news/killer-shooter-in-new-york`

i would like to know how i do that , im not that good in htaccess or friendly URLs but i try to do my best and this is the way that im doing it....

my **.htaccess**

```
    Options All -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?view=$1
```

my **html**

```
//after the header label i add this to include the content
     <?php

          if (isset($_GET["view"])) {

          $view=explode("/",$_GET["view"]);

                include"modules/".$view[0]."-view.php";

          }else{

             include"modules/home-view.php";

          }

      ?>
```

now i got these **links** that take me to the news

```
   <ul class="row news-list">
        <?php $sql=$con->query("SELECT * FROM latest_news LIMIT 4"); 

          while ($row=$sql->fetch_array()) { ?>
  //note: the URLSERVER is the route for example http://localhost/projectNews/    
          <li class="grid_6">
           <a href="<?php echo URLSERVER?>news/<?php echo $row['id']?>/"><?php echo $row['post_title']?></a>

          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
```

the **ouput** of this is `http://localhost/projectNews/news/4/`

once i click the **link** what i would like to do is to add the title of the new after the id of the news like i explained before for example...

`http://localhost/project/news/4/killer-shooter-in-new-york`

can someone of you guys help me please? im a little bit of new on this, thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you tried to get the news by slug, not by id?

Comment: whats you mean by slug?

Comment: "killer-shooter-in-new-york" this part of your URL called "slug" and you can save it in DB by add a field slug and save the urlencode(title) https://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
Then you can retrieve the row by getting the slug and query the database by this slug.